# Symfony2 error: failed to start session, already started by PHP

Tags: php, symfony, session

In the following login script, even though I am starting a session after the user is verified, a symfony exception is thrown stating:

> Failed to start the session: already started by PHP.

following is the login function of mine (I haven't used symfony tokens and security etc. just session):

```
public function loginAction(Request $request){
    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        $mail = $request->get('umail');
        $pass = $request->get('upass');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $rep = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:User');

        $user = $rep->findOneBy(array("email"=>$mail,"pass"=>$pass));
        if($user){
            $id = $user->getId();
            $type = $user->getType();
            $session = new Session();
            $session->start();
            $session->set('id',$id);
            $session->set('type',$type);
            if($type == "admin"){
                return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_homepage');
            }
            elseif ($type == "dis"){
                return $this->redirectToRoute('dis_homepage');
            }
            elseif ($type == "comp"){
                return $this->redirectToRoute('company_homepage');
            }
        }
        else{
            return new Response('not found where mail: '.$mail);
        }
    }
}
```

is there something wrong with the code?
please help..

Comment: You shouldn't start a new session as Symfony handles that for you. You can fetch it using `$session = $request->getSession();` - [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/controller.html#managing-the-session)

Comment: It worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As @JimL said,

> you shouldn't start a new session as Symfony handles that for you. You
>   can fetch it using $session = $request->getSession();

This is important for example if you used a listener that use sessions and then you want to use a Symfony form (who check indirectly if a session has been started).